# Using C# update the document name in a draft DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I’m leveraging the C# API’s EnvelopeDefinition and EnvelopesApi to create envelopes in DocuSign in DRAFT status. I would like to know how I could rename the document that is actually part of the envelope in Draft status. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the EnvelopesApi.UpdateDocuments() method documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/updateList

UpdateDocuments() takes an Envelope Definition object, so in this example I create the Document object to be modified and apply it to an empty EnvelopeDefinition. Using the existing envelope's definition wouldn't be recommended as it comes with extra baggage that's irrelevant to what we're doing here.

```
        string draftEnvelopeId = "000-000-000-000";

        string documentId = "1"; 
        string newFileName = "document.pdf";

        Document renamedDocument = new Document 
        {
            DocumentId = documentId,
            Name = newFileName,
        };
        Document[] documentList = new Document[] { renamedDocument };
        EnvelopeDefinition emptyEnvelope = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            Documents = new List<Document>(documentList) 
        }; 

        EnvelopeDocumentsResult result = envelopesApi.UpdateDocuments(accountId, draftEnvelopeId, emptyEnvelope);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew! Works Great! Really Appreciate it!